# Can't set equal column height with columns created with Angular 2 ngFor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a list of users, and some information about each user. I want to present this information to columns, one column for each user, using ngFor.

Apparently, the content and information of each user is of different length, so it turns out that the height of each col is different.

Of course, I have searched how to make bootstrap cols equal, using the row.eq.height css from bootstrap ([Make cols with eq height](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)), and also searching for other solutions but it doesnt seem to work.

I am using boostrap 4.
Below is my code.
I think the problem lies with the ngFor.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="user of users">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body">
             <label>Username</label>{{user.username}}
             <label>Info</label>{{user.info}}
             <!--more stuff here like user.name etc etc  -->
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<div>
```

**EDIT:**
Added plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/erRmFBeoRsEzHoXN6NE0?p=preview)

Comment: Angular doesn't make styling by itself.I guess you just need to streach your columns by flex css properties.

Comment: Roman, but bootstrap does

Comment: This could be easy to help if we had a plunker to not begin from the scratch

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added a plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of HTML elements, the height of the container is setted by the content.

Pay attention to the fact that `row-eq-height` affects the `col-*` if you work with bootstrap in **flexbox** mode.
You are not using that mode, you can see that there is `floats` for positioning.

You can enable that **flexbox** mode, by using **bootstrap v4** and then it will work, or add the style manually.

***Pay attention:** your plunker has an invalid attribute, it suppose to be **styleUrls** and *styleUrl*.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1GQHpHDhgaTGKxDvxmdm?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this does not work when the length of users are >4. I want for columns for each row. When I add row-eq-height, and users are >4, the row doesn't break; all columns appear to the first row, overflowing all the panel. Check it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/e4woHIKm9kkdowAIENXa?p=preview

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that your `col-*` classes are not applied in the plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/qVaXQ2WdLRPLppMjLmiS?p=preview